- Economics 101
Is it possible to learn economics while studying math? If possible what books do you recommend? I'm looking for books that teach the fundamentals and explain them without any use of mathematics.

Your question is ambiguous - I can't tell whether you're looking for avenues to study economics that will also teach you mathematics (learning econ while studying maths), or whether you mean that you don't yet know any economics, and you want a book which teaches econ before you've learnt any maths.


I have questions about learning economics, is it possible to learn it while studying math?

It is not just possible, its great advantage. Economics nowadays is quite mathematical subject. Its not uncommon for people who do PhD in economics to come from physics or math background.

If possible what books do you recommend? I'm looking for books that teach the fundamentals and explain them without any use of mathematics.

Its difficult to find a economic textbook that has absolutely no math nowadays. If you insist on absolutely no math then you can try some popular economics books, I think; The Economics Book Big Ideas Simply Explained by DK publishing is good book.
Many undergraduate textbooks are not math heavy. Undergraduate textbooks are for the most part heavily standardized and you will find pretty much every peer reviewed undergraduate textbook covers the same stuff so you can pick really any that is most convenient for you. I like Mankiw Principles of Economics, I think it  is written very well and its also used at many universities, but really you could pick any standard undergraduate textbook and get pretty much the same thing.
